# NSPredicate to filter core data by month

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a Core Data model with a Date property, and I want to filter the database by only pulling out data from whatever month is currently being displayed on the calendar.

```
func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar)
    {
        
        let currentPageDate = calendar.currentPage

        let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: currentPageDate)
        
        fetchEvents(month: month)
        
        print(eventsInMonth!.count)
    }
```

This variable is stored as an int. This is the function I am currently using to load the events in from the Core data:

```
 func fetchEvents(month: Int)
{
    //fetch the data from core data to display in the table view
    do
    {
        let request = Event.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest

        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "startTime ==  %@", month)

        request.predicate = pred
        
        self.eventsInMonth = try context.fetch(request)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            self.fsCalednar.reloadData()
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        
    }
}
```

How can format the NSPredicate so it will only pull out data whose month is equal to "05" for example?

Comment: Just the month might be not sufficient. You will get the May events of every year. Save the full date as `Date` and create a predicate `startTime >= 1.5.2021 && startTime < 1.6.2021`

Comment: If the data type of month is Int, change the predicate line to let pred = NSPredicate(format: "startTime ==  %i", month)

Comment: I actually just came across a use case to pull out all dates in any year in certain months. How would one do that? @vadian